# The role of subgradient in programming with nonsmooth functions

Tags: convex-optimization, global-optimization

It is obvious that there is similarity between subgradient and gradient. The subgradient of smooth functions is reduced to gradient. I have two questions.

The first is does there exist subgradient decent method (analogous to the well known gradient decent mothod) in nonsmooth problems.

The second is, given a nonsmooth function, how to determine the subgradient? (by computer)

Summarily, I have no idea of the role of subgradient in programming of nonsmooth functions. Is it just a concept or a very useful tool (like gradient)?

Comment: There is an obvious Google search here ("subgradient descent")... 

Comment: this is not a research level MO question; please have a look at any of the textbooks on nonsmooth stuff; for convex optimization: "introductory lectures on convex optimization" by Yu. Nesterov; for nonconvex, nonsmooth functions, subdifferential calculus is much more tricky, but a practical starting point it "Nonsmooth analysis" by F. Clarke; also, have a look at online slides of S. Boyd's 364b course at stanford...